# Is it ok to install vinyl windows from several different manufacturers?

Tags: windows

We are looking at replacing all of the windows in our home which are original aluminum from 1963. We were going to go with all Milgard retrofit (aluminum out of budget) but unfortunately they don't carry three windows/sliding glass doors that are large enough. The only window manufacturer who does retrofit that would fit the size is Jeld-Wen. Would you recommend mixing the two brands (large windows/door in Jeld-Wen and all other windows Milgard---do they look enough alike it will not look terrible?) or go with all Jeld-Wen windows/doors? I cannot tell from the Jeld-Wen website alone if they would match and there is no showroom near us. I should mention that we already have two Milgard Tuscany sliding doors and one window that will not be replaced from a previous kitchen renovation. We live in SoCal so weather not an issue. Thank you!

Comment: If everything is basically the same color, I can't see how this would matter much at all. Navy blue for some and orange for others - no. White for all - yes, whites vary a bit but really doesn't matter. "Off white" for all - probably OK, though then it gets to what direction the "off" goes - gray vs. beige.

Comment: When my house was appraised the appraiser noted I had different brand windows. I don't know if or how much that affected the appraisal.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Would be white on all windows.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar questions on a new building project. I couldn't see enough difference in the frame designs to worry about, so the primary concern was keeping the same color of windows throughout the home. The window companies were glad to give small color samples for comparisons.  My research taught me that there were primarily 2 colors of vinyl windows on the market: white and almond, with very limited variations. The reason for the limited choice has to do with thermal expansion, as color tinted vinyl windows result in too many warranty claims. (Wouldn't it be nice get brown, or wood-toned vinyl windows?)

I went with 3 different window manufactures, got the function I wanted and saved over a thousand dollars. I chose frames that all had a similar exterior reveal (similar frame widths). I also stayed with the same mullion pattern for every window.  Most of the interior sides of the windows were covered with curtains or blinds. After installation, I never gave any thought to the minor differences in the window constructions. Nor did I ever hear any comments about the window manufacture mix, just comments on the nice light.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The questions you probably should ask yourself are:

Why am I replacing them?

How long will I be living there?

If you are thinking more than 10 years and if you live in are that has cold winters or is windy then the answer would have to be buy a better window.

Average windows leak air and have cold glass and frames

With the right window you will be more comfortable your utility bill will be lower and it will be a selling point when you decide to move.

Spend some time online and search for European style windows.  You will be surprised what you will find.

Roofing, cladding and windows are long term purchases.

Good Luck

Comment: We will look into the European style- we live in SoCal so weather not an issue here thankfully. Thank you very much for the information!